Smallest dimensional faithful complex representation of $\mathrm{PSL}(k,q)$
For given $k>1$ and $q$ a prime power, what is the minimal dimension, as a function of $(k,q)$, for which a faithful complex representation of the projective special linear group over $\mathbb{F}_q$, $\mathrm{PSL}(k,q)$, exists? A constructive approach would be great, not just the characters, once we have the dimension, i.e. a construction of the actual representation for that minimal, or close to minimal, dimension.
Is it the case that if $p$, the prime dividing $q$, is less than $2k+1$, then we have a $k-1$ dimensional faithful complex representation?
I'm interested in the above because ultimately what I'm after is for a given $d$ I'd like to maximize the order of $\mathrm{PSL}(k,q)$ such that a faithful complex representation of $\mathrm{PSL}(k,q)$ exists of dimension $d$.
We have $|\mathrm{PSL}(k,q)| =  \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(q^k-q^i)}{(q-1) gcd(k,q-1) }$, so ultimately I'd like to maximize this over $(k,q)$ for a fixed $d$ such that a faithful representation exists in dimension $d$. It's perfectly fine if it can't be done for all $d$ only for even $d$ or odd $d$ or some other constraint on $d$, but the approach should work at least with infinitely many $d$.
Examples for low $k$ and/or $q$ can be obtained by computer algebra or by looking up character tables, some of these are listed in Possible degrees of faithful projective representations of $\mathrm{PSL}(k,q)$ and $\mathrm{Sp}(2k,q)$ over complex numbers but I'm after general statements.

I have partially answered this question in my answer and comments to previous questions, so I will make this answer Community wiki: By results of Landazuri-Seitz and Tiep- Zalesski, some of which which are also tabulated in the papers of M.J. Collins, when $k \geq 3,$ the group ${\rm PSL}(k,q)$ has no (faithful) complex irreducible character of degree less than $q^{k-1}+1$, with the exception of ${\rm PSL}(4,3)$, where the minimal possible degree is $26$.
The group ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ (apart from the small cases when it is not simple) has no non-trivial complex irreducible character of degree less than $\frac{q-1}{2}.$
In particular, it is never possible for a simple ${\rm PSL}(k,q)$ to have a non-trivial complex irreducible character of degree $k-1$ or less.

There is one slight issue here, which is if we want the exact minimum dimension then these expressions are almost right, but it will depend in a finnicky way on $n$ and $q$. For example, for $PSL_2(q)$, the smallest representation is dimension $(q-1)/2$ or $(q+1)/2$, because for half the (odd!) $q$s the $(q-1)/2$-dimensional representation is of $SL$, not $PSL$. For $q$ even, of course it is $q-1$. I guess it depends on whether exact dimensions are needed or just good bounds.

@DavidA.Craven Exact dimensions are not really needed, but the construction should work for infinitely many $d$ so it's okay if only works for large $d$ (and, I suppose, consequently for large $k$ and/or $q$) and it doesn't have to be all integers above a certain bound, it's okay to have it just for even $d$ or $d$ a power of 2, or anything that can be taken to infinity. I understand there isn't much of a pattern for low $k$ but perhaps for large enough ones?

And the representation doesn't have to be irreducible actually, just faithful, so edited to post.

If the bound $d \ge q^{k-1}+1$ is fairly tight, then given the formula for the order of group that you want to maximize, it seems like you want $k$ to be as large as possible (so $q$ as small as possible), so that there are lots of terms in the product. In particular it seems like you always want to take $q$ prime and incorporate any exponent you might've had into $k$, unless there's a big issue w the $gcd(k,q-1)$ term.

For $k \geq 2,$ the faithful complex representation  of lowest dimension of ${\rm PSL}(k,q)$ is necessarily irreducible ( even in the degenerate cases when ${\rm PSL}(k,q)$ is not simple.
